# Change Calculator // Struggling with C and Functions

Tags: c, function

I've just started learning C so bear with me. I'm trying to figure out how to program a change calculator using functions. I just need help on learning how to structure it. I figured out the formulas I need to use below:

```
int dollars = float money / 1

float quarters = money – dollars

int quartercount = quarters / .25

float dimes = quarters - (quartercount*.25)

int dimescount = dimes / .10

float nickels = dimes – (dimescount*.10)

int nickelcount = nickels / .05

float pennies = nickels – (nickelcount*.05)

int pennycount = pennies / .01
```

EDIT: I should've made that more clear sorry. we would be inputing the change amount and it would display what dollars and coins it would take to make that change.

Any amount of help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tell us more about the requirements of the function.  What do you want to pass in and what do you want out?  I'm assuming money is the input, and the number of quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies are the output?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i should've made that more clear sorry. we would be inputing the change amount and it would display what dollars and coins it would take to make that change.

Comment: Suggest using `double` rather than `float` if code is to use floating point for money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic structure is like this.  But it depends if you need to return the values, or just print them (like this example).

```
void changeCalculator(float money) {
    int dollars = money / 1;
    printf("Dollars = %d",dollars);
    float quarters = money – dollars;
    int quartercount = quarters / .25;
    printf("Quarters = %d",quartercount );
    float dimes = quarters - (quartercount*.25);
    int dimescount = dimes / .10;
    printf("Dimes= %d",dimescount);
    float nickels = dimes – (dimescount*.10);
    int nickelcount = nickels / .05;
    printf("Nickels= %d",nickelcount );
    float pennies = nickels – (nickelcount*.05);
    int pennycount = pennies / .01;
    printf("Pennies= %d",pennycount );
}
```

Comment: thanks! if I were to print the counts of the change, where would i put that? inside the main or a seperate one?

Comment: Just use printf.  The %d just means you are going to give it an int afterwards.  Mark it as the answer if it helps!

Comment: oh i see now. how do i incorporate the "int main" to the program

Comment: sounds like you are trying to get your homework answered :) If you want you can just call this function from the main() function by calling changeCalculator(money) where money is a float value you pass in.

Comment: im just trying to understand it better :b i didn't really want it completed for me. thanks for the help!